# Different Behavior on Different Faces With Procedural Texturing

Tags: node-editor, procedural

I applied a procedural texture on a cube where I want red to be higher than white. At the picture shown, the top face is correct but the front face is wrong. This is just at simple cube, all normals are facing outward.
 [image: Procedural Texture as applied on cube sphere and monkey]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert a displacement node between the height value and the output.

[image]

This displacement node will calculate the direction appropriately considering the given height. Here you need to scale it negatively in order to have white higher than red.

Comment: It worked. For my project, the value I needed is a positive number! Thanks a lot